# What exactly is a preplacement letter in an academic job in an english speaking country?

Tags: job

I applied for one job in a state-funded research organization. After the interview I received a pre-placement letter in which they say that before an offer of appointment can be made, some pre-appoitment enquiries will be made - they want me to send additional documents (scans of passport, diploma etc.). Does that mean that I will be offered the job? Or this is normal to ask from several candidates?

Comment: Please post an update when you find out if you got the job.  It's quite odd to request a copy of a passport from someone who has not accepted a job offer yet.  Hopefully they did not ask for the original passport to be sent to them.

Comment: Which country? If the offer letter is legally binding, it may make sense to check the employability before writing the offer letter.

Comment: @DCTLib it is the UK

Comment: It means they intend to make an offer once all the appropriate checks (allowed to work in the country, clean background check, proper certificates if required, ...) are successfully passed.